# Import Leaflet.awesome-marker in angular/cli component

Tags: leaflet, angular-cli

I want to use the [Leaflet.awesome-marker](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers) plugin in my angular project.

I installed the package throught yarn and imported in my component using

```
import * as awesome from 'leaflet.awesome-marker';
```

But I receive the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'leaflet.awesome-marker'
```

Doing the same thing with the `geojson` module works fine, why not with this one?

Comment: did you managed to import the module?

Comment: Nope, I used leaflet custom div marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing `leaflet.awesome-markers`, not `leaflet.awesome-marker`